# Apache storm - Map topology with storm cluster

Tags: apache-storm

I read many sites related to Storm.
But still I cannot map topology into storm cluster perfectly.

Please help me to understand this.

In storm cluster there are terms like

- Supervisor
- Worker node
- Worker processor
- Workers
- Slots
- Executer
- Tasks

In topology, there are

- Spout
- Bolt

Also there is possible to configure

- numWorkers
- parallelism

So anyone please relate all these thing to help me.

I want to know like, each spout/bolt is act executer or is it the task.
If parallelism hint is given, the count of which entity will increase.
If num workers set, which one's count is that.

All these things to map with storm cluster.
I already worked in a project. So I know the topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Physical Cluster Setup:**

The term **node** usually refers to a physical **machine** (or a VM) in your cluster. On each node a **supervisor** is running in an own JVM. Supervisor have **worker slots**. This is a logical configuration and tells how many worker can be started by a supervisor. Each **worker** (if started) runs in an own JVM (thus, some people call it worker process). *In summary: on a node there is one supervisor JVM and up to number-of-worker-slots worker JVMs.* Therefore, the node a worker JVM is running on, can be called worker node. While the supervisor is running all the time, workers are started if needed, ie, if topologies are deployed, and stopped when a topology is killed. Within a worker, **executors** are running as **threads** (ie, each executor maps to an own thread).

**Logical Topology Setup:**

Topologies are build out of **Spouts** (also called sources, ie, operators with no incoming data stream) and **Bolts** (regular operators with at least one incoming data stream and any number of outgoing data streams -- if there is no outgoing data stream, a Bolt is also called **sink**). For each Spout/Bolt you can configure two parameters:

1. the number of tasks
2. the dop (**degree of parallelism**, called `parallelism_hint`), ie, the number of executors you want to have for a Spout/Bolt

**Tasks** are logical unit of works (ie, something passive). Let's assume you use `fieldsGrouping` connection pattern. Thus, the data stream is partitioned into number-of-tasks many sub-streams. Tasks are assigned to executors, ie, each executor processes one or multiple tasks. This implies, that you cannot have less tasks than executors (ie, parallelism); otherwise, there would be a thread without any work to do.

See the Storm documentation for further details (https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html). Furthermore, there are many other question on SO about task/executors in Storm.

Last but not least, you can configure the `numberOfWorkers` for a topology. This parameter indicates, how many workers should be started to run the topology. The overall number of executors for a topology is the sum of dops over all Spouts/Bolts. All executors will be evenly distributes over all available worker JVMs.

Furthermore, a single worker can only run executors of a single topology. This is done for fault-tolerance reasons, ie, topologies are isolated from each other. At the same time, a worker itself can run any number of executors.